# According to Makefile write cmake CMakeList

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am learning the [nvidia-video-codec-sdk](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk) example. It manage the project through `Makefile`, and it works fine in my computer.

Now, I want to use `cmake` to manage the project, so I need to write the `CMakeList.txt`, but I can't work it properly. I just try the `NvDecodeGL`.

**CMakeList.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(NvDecodeGL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -DINIT_CUDA_GL=1 -g")

find_library(X11_LIBRARY X11 HINTS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
find_library(GL_LIBRARY GL HINTS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
find_library(GLU_LIBRARY GLU HINTS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
find_library(Xmu_LIBRARY Xmu HINTS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
find_library(glut_LIBRARY glut HINTS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
find_library(libGLEW_LIBRARY GLEW HINTS ../common/lib//linux/x86_64)
find_library(pthread_LIBRARY pthread HINTS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../common/inc)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(./)

set(SOURCE_FILES
    ../common/src/dynlink_cuda.cpp
    ../common/src/dynlink_nvcuvid.cpp
    ../common/src/cudaModuleMgr.cpp
    cudaProcessFrame.cpp
    FrameQueue.cpp
    ImageGL.cpp
    NV12ToARGB_drvapi.cu
    NvDecodeGL.cpp
    VideoDecoder.cpp
    VideoParser.cpp
    VideoSource.cpp
    )

add_executable(NvDecodeGL ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(NvDecodeGL -ldl ${X11_LIBRARY} ${GL_LIBRARY} ${GLU_LIBRARY} ${X11_LIBRARY} ${Xmu_LIBRARY} ${glut_LIBRARY} ${libGLEW_LIBRARY} ${pthread_LIBRARY})
```

**Error**:

```
undefined reference to `__glewGenProgramsARB' ....
```

**Update**:
    Now everything is Ok. At this problem, I make two mistakes, one is the IDE cache, and another is the resource relate directory. Correcting those. Thanks all!

Comment: What is variable `NvDEcodeGL_LINKER_LIBS` for? You never set it in your code, but use for linking.

Comment: sorry, it is a mistake. But if NvDEcodeGL_LINKER_LIBS not set, it is empty. now fix to: target_link_libraries(NvDecodeGL -ldl ${X11_LIBRARY} ${GL_LIBRARY} ${GLU_LIBRARY} ${X11_LIBRARY} ${Xmu_LIBRARY} ${glut_LIBRARY} ${libGLEW_LIBRARY} ${pthread_LIBRARY}) getting the same error as before.

Comment: oh, the ide cache makes mistake, delete all the cache. now it pass compiling. But at runtime, getting the error: [1]    7890 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./NvDecodeGL. ( make at NvDecodeGL folder, every works fine)

Comment: Please, [edit] your question post and update information in it in accordance to your comments. Stack Overflow policy is to collect important information in the question post, not in the comments.

Comment: I do it, thanks a lot@Tsyvarev